# Play a sound in Android when i start application

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to play a music sound when my application starts.
I used the code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.counting1to5song);
        mp.start();
```

and the song is in res/raw folder. But when I install the application in my phone and then open, the app crashes!!!

Anyone can give me any help to get this sound properly function?

Comment: can you post the logcat ?

Comment: what is the logcat? how can i get that? sory, i don't know.

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Logcat

Comment: Have you tried looking at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861859/implement-sound-in-android-application

Comment: All ready tried to looking to that question. But the app crashes when it starts too. I find Logcat in Android Studio but nothing apears.

Comment: You're missing any kind of error handling. Don't take for granted that all API calls will succeed. For example, `MediaPlayer.create` will return `null` if it fails, and `MediaPlayer.start` will throw an exception if you call it when the media player is in the wrong state.

Comment: All ready solved, i was trying play a .wav sound but now i tried with MP3 and i was suceeded

Answer (score 1):

use this code an try it:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: The same problem. The app crashes when starts. But when i put that code in "new MediaPlayer();" is saying that the variable is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new folder called "raw" inside "debug" folder. To create it, right-click on "debug" folder > new > directory > and in name it "raw":

To add files just drag the .wav/.mp3 files to "raw" folder.

2. Import media player:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
```

3. Declare MediaPlayer global variable(s):

```
public MediaPlayer mp1;
```

4. Inside `onCreate` method, assign the corresponding sounds:

```
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, raw.my_sound_name);
```

5. Finally, you can use methods:

```
mp1.start() / mp1.stop() / mp1.pause()
```